# Match word after pattern and append a suffix in a file using sed?

Tags: regex, linux, bash, shell, sed

I have multiple files like this one:

```
CREATE TABLE VAI_TEST
   (
      TEST VARCHAR2(4000)
   ) ;
```

Only the first line is relevant. I need to replace VAI_TEST with VAI_TEST_TEMP.
The result should be like this:

```
CREATE TABLE VAI_TEST_TEMP
   (
      TEST VARCHAR2(4000)
   ) ;
```

I've found multiple regex pattern that match VAI_TEST e.g.

- `(?:CREATE TABLE )([A-Za-z_]*)[\r\n]`
- `(?:.* TABLE )(.*$)`
- `CREATE TABLE (.*)\n`
- `(?:.* TABLE )(.*)\n`

Probably there are more and better patterns.
My problem is to replace the content of capture group 1 with the content and the suffix.

I've tried multiple sed combinations but mostly nothing happens or I get an error for a wrong regex pattern (with -r flag) or invalid reference \1 (with -e) flag.

In the end I want to use the command in a bash script. Additionally it would be helpful if the new name could be saved in a variable to use it in further steps.

What is a good way to achieve this?

Comment: `sed 's/VAI_TEST$/&_TEMP/' file` or `sed 's/CREATE TABLE .*/&_TEMP/' file`

Comment: Does that work for you? If not, what is wrong? Please show your script.

Comment: `VAI_TEST` what is actually known about this ? It looks like non-whitespace `\S` Something like `/CREATE[ \t]+TABLE[ \t]+(\S+)/` might be beneficial.

Comment: I should have mentioned that VAI_TEST is variable. So each file has it's own name. In the next file it is e.g. VAI_STATUS.

Comment: Why not simply: `sed 's|VAI_TEST|VAI_TEST_TEMP|'`? I don't see the need of using capture groups and such.

Comment: `sed '/^CREATE TABLE/s/[^ ]*$/&_TEMP/'` - on lines matching CREATE TABLE, add _TEMP to the non-space characters before the linebreak.

Comment: Thanks @stevesliva
It works, I added the -i flag to work with the file.
If you write it as answer I would accept it

Comment: @Emare - it was substantially similar to Wiktor's second suggestion... wasn't sure that didn't solve it for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sed '/^CREATE TABLE/s/[^ ]*$/&_TEMP/' file`

- `/^CREATE TABLE/` - on lines beginning with "CREATE TABLE",
- `s/[^ ]*$/` - replace non-space characters (`[^ ]`) before the endline (`$`) with:
- `&_TEMP` - `&` -- whatever those characters were-- suffixed with "_TEMP"

Answer (score 1):

Consider

```
sed -i 's/CREATE TABLE [^[:space:]]\{1,\}$/&_TEMP/' file
```

`[^[:space:]]` is for any symbol other than whitespace and `\{1,\}` repeats it one or more times. `&` stands for the matched content.